# Difference between tensor product and main effects plus interaction in mgcv

Tags: r, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I was under the impression that using `te` and adding the main effects with `s` plus the interaction with `ti` is the same (in a GAM model, estimated with `mgcv`).

However:

```
library( mgcv )
library( gamair )
data( brains )

tm <- gam(medFPQ~te(Y,X,k=10),data=brain,family=Gamma(link=log))
tm1 <- gam(medFPQ ~ s(Y,k=10,bs="cr") + s(X,bs="cr",k=10) +
         ti(X,Y,k=10), data=brain, family=Gamma(link=log))

predict(tm)[955]
predict(tm1)[955]
```

(The example is copied verbatim from Simon Wood's GAM book, page 335, so the specification should be correct.)

So, aren't these two formulations equivalent...?

Comment: I think the Q&A I linked to answers this; there are more smoothness parameters to estimate in the decomposed model, beyond differences that might crop up due to using different parameterisations of the same model.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson : Thank you Gavin, I somehow missed that question.